# How to call a function with context in django CB list view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

This is my view:

```
class viewbloglistview(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Blog
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_template_names(self):
        if True:  
            return ['blog/view_blogs.html']
        else:
            return ['blog/blog_list.html']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.all().order_by('-blog_views')[:20]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(viewbloglistview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        context['categories_list'] = categories.objects.all()
        return context
```

This is my function in models.py file:

```
    def categories_count(self):
        categories_count = categories.objects.annotate(blog_count=Count('blogs')).values_list('Title','blog_count')
        return categories_count
```

I want call the function in my views with a context name to render the activity in my template..

Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem??

Thank you

Comment: Is this a method *in* the class-based view?

Comment: Not actually not a method...The method function I have done is in my models.py file I just want to call it in my list view to render it in my template

Comment: then why does it have a `self` method? Perhaps it would be better to provide some sample template, etc. such that the problem is more clear.

Comment: just like this I have done it in detail view "'categories_count' : blog_details.categories_count(),"...Is there any way to do it in CBV list view

Comment: If you can call it in your detail view, why can't you call it in your list view? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a python problem, your question is unclear but based on what you said:

- Case the function in in your model.py alone:

  ```
  from . import model.py
  // code
  categories_count()
  ```
- Case the function is a method in a class as it is shown on you code with the self parameter in it:

  ```
  from . import model.py
  // code
  classname.categories_count()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have named your class as 'categories' (which should have been named as Category in the first place),

categories_count should have been in a manager as you are querying in a class level. Say you don't want a manager and want to keep the code inside the model, then you can use it as a class method.

```
@classmethod
def categories_count(cls):
    return cls.objects.annotate(blog_count=Count('blogs')).values_list('Title','blog_count')
```

and in the views use it as

```
categories.categories_count()
```

Just remember that the regular methods with the 'self' argument like the one you have, should only be used when you are dealing with a single instance, not when you are accessing the class itself.